# How to add custom link in views field list?

Tags: views

I have created a view and added some data field, and I want to add a link field, which has the title "Approve." Whenever the administrator users click on that link, an AJAX call should update the database.

How can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for functionality similar to the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag).

Comment: I want a custom ajax link on view fields list.

Comment: The flag module has the same functionality. You could always take a look at the code.